# Update multiple tables in a single update statement with left join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I realise what I'm asking for may be impossible.  I want to perform an UPDATE on two separate tables based on a LEFT JOIN and a WHERE clause.  This is my attempt:

```
UPDATE  PERIODDATES as pd, periods2 as p2
SET     pd.[PERIODCODE] = @PERIODCODE,
     p2.[USERCODE] = @USERCODE
             left join periods2 AS p2
    ON  pdates.schemeid = p2.schemeid AND

WHERE [SCHEMEID] = @SCHEMEID
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. You can only update one table in one statement.  You will have to split this out in to two statements.

Edit:

Updating two tables in one statement is actually possible but will need to create a View using a `UNION` that contains both the tables you want to update.  You can then update the View which will then update the underlying tables.

It seems like a bit of hack to me but it will work.

Comment: I agree this seems a bit like a hack, think I'll separate the statement up pending any other answers.  Any reasons why this isn't possible then?  It seems like it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Reviving a an old question here, but... you can simulate updating multiple tables in a single query via two UPDATE queries wrapped in a transaction. This way you don't have to get messy using up-datable views and no changes will be made unless both tables update successfully:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE PERIODDATES AS pd
SET pd.PeriodCode = @PeriodCode
WHERE [SCHEMEID] = @SCHEMEID;

UPDATE periods2 AS pd2
SET pd2.[USERCODE] = @USERCODE
WHERE [SCHEMEID] = @SCHEMEID;

COMMIT;
```

for your inserts, you can use either @@IDENTITY, or OUTPUT INTO to grab the id of the new record to use in the second table, ie:

```
DECLARE @ID int;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO PERIODDATES( PeriodCode ) AS pd
VALUES ( @PeriodCode )
WHERE [SCHEMEID] = @SCHEMEID;

SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO periods2( [SCHEMEID], [USERCODE] ) AS pd2
VALUES ( @ID, @USERCODE );

COMMIT;
```